# service file for golang app

Tags: systemd

So I wrote a golang app which I want initialized by `systemd` whenever my server gets a reboot.

Here's the service file:-

```
[Unit]
Description=golang wiki initialization

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/tmp/gowiki.pid-3030
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/var/www
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'daemonize -o stdout.log -e stderr.log /var/www/wiki'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It appears to work well whenever I reboot the server but I am still running into slightly irritating problem when I am manually starting or restarting `gowiki` like this in terminal:-

```
systemctl start gowiki
```

or

```
systemctl restart gowiki
```

This does get my gowiki process running; however, after I execute my `systemctl start gowiki` command, I am frozen in my terminal and the command does not seem to exit until I manually force a Ctrl-C.

What am I doing wrong to be causing this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This worked.

```
[Unit]
Description=golang wiki initialization

[Service]
PIDFile=/tmp/gowiki.pid-4040
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/var/www
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/var/www/wiki'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Because the `Type=forking` services expect the parent service to exit before the service has actually started. If the parent never exits, then systemctl start will not give you back a prompt because it doesn't think that it's done executing.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind adjusting your code a little for systemd the cleanest solution I've found thus far is using the SDNotify-signal.

```
import "github.com/coreos/go-systemd/daemon"

func main() {
    // Important init stuff here
    ....

    // Notify systemd that we're ready
    sent, e := daemon.SdNotify(false, "READY=1")
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal(e)
    }
    if !sent {
        log.Printf("SystemD notify NOT sent\n")
    }

    // And do something blocking like listening for HTTP(s)
```

- It has no CGO-deps
- The code also works on non-systemd systems (in this case it emits a warning notify not sent)
- If you want a working example: https://github.com/mpdroog/dnsleak

Your corresponding systemd unit-file:

```
[Unit]
Description=golang wiki initialization
After=network.target
Requires=network.target

[Service]
Type=notify

Restart=always
RestartSec=30
TimeoutStartSec=0

WorkingDirectory=/var/www
ExecStart=/var/www/wiki
User=www-data
Group=www-data
NoNewPrivileges=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```